# if application "Safari" visible is false then (AppleScript)

Tags: safari, applescript

I would like to check if Safari is visible, my AppleScript code was this, but it doesn't work ... How can I check the visible with AppleScript?

```
if application "Safari" visible is false then
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
    end tell
end if
```

Comment: Do you mean, visible in part/full or do you mean frontmost, ie top/active window?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,,,

```
tell application "System Events"
    if visible of process "Safari" is false then
        tell application "Safari" to activate
    end if
end tell
```

That will only work if it's running, but hidden, btw. If you simply want the script to 'fetch' Safari, just activate it without any check

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the syntax of code may not be correct. This is how I would write it:

```
if visible of application "Safari" is false then 
    --Do Something
end if
```

Secondly, an app has to be already activated to have an value for boolean `visible`. What you might want instead is `set frontmost to true`.